# Is there a formula to find the number of cases where $N$ is expressed as the sum of $M$ integers?

Tags: probability, natural-numbers

For given a nonnegative integer number $N$ and $M$, I want to find how many cases exist where $N$ can be expressed as the sum of $M$ integers.

For example, if $N=5$ and $M=2$, there are only three cases, i.e., $(0,5)$, $(1,4)$, and $(2,3)$.

If $N=5$ and $M=3$, there are only five cases, i.e., $(0,0,5)$, $(0,1,4)$, $(0,2,3)$, $(1,1,3)$, and $(1,2,2)$.

Is there a formula to find the number of cases where $N$ is expressed as the sum of arbitrary $M$ integers?

Comment: This is related to partitions (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))

Comment: I assume you would like the integers to be nonnegative. See also https://oeis.org/A008284 and the resources there. Might be found in the literature as the number of partitions of $N$ into (at most) $M$ parts.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Very helpful to me.